# enable authentication in mqtt username and password

Tags: configuration, mqtt

changes in mqtt configuration file for authentication with username and password conf file setting`use_identity_as_username true`

```
username:password
password_file
```

what changes we need to do in configuration file

Comment: MQTT is a protocol, not an implementation. What server are you trying to configure?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Mosquitto MQTT broker` and I do like this:

Set `allow_anonymous false`

```
password_file file_path
```

Then try starting broker with conf file::::

From command prompt:

```
c:\>mosquitto\mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf
```

//